# Magento error "Failed opening"

Tags: magento

When I am disabling a purchased module in magento and load the magento admin. Then it shows me error:

> RR (3): Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mage/Sarp/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='app/code/local:app/code/community:app/code/core:lib:.') in lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93"

I have googled and got this link: http://kb.magenting.com/content/22/29/en/solution-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory-in-includes-src-varien_autoloadphp-on-line-93.html.

I have follow all this steps. But no results. I don't have ssh access.

Comment: After disabling this module did you clear cache? What type of access do you have to this site (ftp)? Also I dont think it cause by "compilation" been enable because it not look for `include_path='includes/src:` path

Comment: Yes. I cleared the cache. But still problem. I have ftp access.

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not have a module named Sarp. So to me it looks like you are still having some code like `Mage::helper('sarp')` somewhere (maybe in phtml) but the module don't exist.